# How do I disable Window 10's Storage Sense permanently?

Tags: windows-10, storage

Windows 10 gave me a notification "We have turned on Storage Sense for you".

Storage Sense was turned off in Settings -> System -> Storage, but Windows 10 turned itself back on and deleted files.

How do I kill Storage Sense permanently?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is just to disable Storage Sense via the group policy. I'm not sure if this requires Windows 10 Pro.

Open the start menu and type `group policy` or `gpedit` and press enter. Change `Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Storage Sense > Allow Storage Sense` to **Disabled**. You can confirm that this worked by attempting to enable Storage Sense through the Windows settings (the toggle should be forced off).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

open start, run `regedit` and navigate to

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\StorageSense\Parameters\StoragePolicy`

Right click `01` -> **Modify** and set Value data to `0`.  Setting this to 0 will flip the StorageSense Toggle off.

Next Right Click the **StoragePolicy key (folder)**, and click **permissions**. Then Click **Advanced Button**.  Click **Disable inhertance** button and choose to **Convert inherited permissions into explicit permissions on this object.**

Next for-each Principal in the list above, **select it** and press **Edit button**.
**Uncheck**  Full Control, but leave Read **checked**. Click **OK**.

After all Access is set to read only, click **Apply**, Click **OK**. Click **OK**.

Close the regedit and that should be it. If you try to turn it back on though Settings -> System -> Storage, the toggle should fail to enable.

Comment: This could probably be done in a simpler way – adding an explicit Deny entry (just for Write, of course) will always override an inherited Allow.

Comment: Maybe, not sure. Denying Full Control, would also deny read access.  I don't know what that would do.

Comment: It’s unnecessary to modify the registry permissions if you change the group policy itself, the reason the setting is being reset, is because it’s not explicitly turned off with a group policy. Given we’re at the end of updates to Windows 10 there is little to no chance of an update resetting the policy

Comment: @Ramhound yes that would work -- assuming one is able to use the group policy editor.

Comment: @gattsbr - You can always just modify the key that group policy uses for enforcement.  The only possible limitation is if the policy itself can be applied to Windows 10 Home

Comment: @Ramhound Again, "assuming one is able to use the gropy policy editor".

Comment: @gattsbr - You don't need the group policy editor if the you modify the registry key responsible for the policy itself.